# VC 2017 Runtime deployment methods

Tags: visual-c++, windows-installer, msvcrt, redistributable

**Hi!**

Could someone answear my question, please?

I have two options with the **VC++** deployment.
I can use:

1. call redistrutable executable (**the vcredist_x86.exe**)
2. add the only one important **CRT merge module**

Both solutions are acceptable for me.
Which would be better for home desktop's users?

*Thank you very much*

Comment: The merge module is pretty much a slamdunk I'd say, nothing that pretty about a Microsoft copyright notice.  You do overlook option #3, local deployment.  Simply copying vcruntime140.dll and (perhaps) msvcp140.dll into the same directory as the deployed .exe.  Out of reach from somebody else's screwy installer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment.
Copying to the app's directory has disadvanteges.
Windows can not update them.

Comment: Microsoft has given up on deploying security updates for these DLLs.  They tried to make it work by storing these DLLs in the winsxs cache at VS2005.  But it was a complete nightmare for programmers that could not get the manifest right or simply had no idea how to deploy to winsxs.  So they gave up on it at VS2010.  No updates have ever been delivered through Windows Update since then.  So you are trying to enable an option that will never be used.

Comment: Option 4: Statically link to the CRT.

Comment: @zett42 thank you, I use statically linked CRT in a setup app, but here it is not a good idea, because I need to share libs with other apps. There is not a reason for such solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is really what kind of installer/setup solution you are using? The Merge Modules are if you use an MSI-based installer. The other is generic enough you can usually work it into any standard installer assuming that the install itself elevates with administrator rights.

> Note that the CRT deployment is one of the areas that UWP apps on Windows Store just takes care of for you.

Comment: I highly appreciate the answer. I have the WIX project with a custom bootstraper. The MSM is better for me, because it is significally smaller (**1MB**), Microsoft_VC141_CRT_x86.msm, and the redistributable's size is **14MB**.
The problem is, that I need a good solution for customers, not me...

Comment: > The other is generic enough you can usually work it into any standard installer assuming that the install itself elevates with administrator rights

It must be noted that the vcredist executable is itself a WIX Burn program, containing MSIs for the VC redict, and MSUs for UCRT. MSIs inside the exe will *not* allow you to use it inside your MSI (unless you run it in UI part of installation; so it's only useful for *other* types of installer).